# PHP remove specific character and number from beginning of string

Tags: php

I want to remove brackets and number from beginning of string but problem is brackets and number is coming only specific string not all.

for example following is my string.

```
1) [4] Mustangs 8u
2) Pool a First Place
3) Team slect
4) [3] In pruduct
```

so above you can see only 1 and 4 string have number with brackets at beginning of  string so i want to only remove that if that found in string.

I write following code but is not work.

```
<?php

foreach ($grouped as $round_number => $group) {

        $team_1_name = $group->team_1_name;
        $new_str = preg_replace('/^([0-9]* \w+ )?(.*)$/', '$2', $team_1_name);

        $date = date ('F d, Y g:iA', $unix_time);

    }

?>
```

Comment: You mean string [4] Mustangs 8u must be Mustangs 8u after code?

Comment: Yes, also sting ' [3] In pruduct'  there are many sting in loop but i found some with number and brackets so i only remove those stings in loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try regular expression `/^(\[[0-9]\]?\s?)/` as:

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/^(\[[0-9]\]?\s?)/', '$2', $team_1_name);
```

For reference: [regexr](https://regexr.com/3s05r)

Answer (score 2):

In case your numbers are multi digit (i.e. '[11] In pruduct')...

```
echo preg_replace('/^(\[\d*\]?\s?)/', '$2', $team_1_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead regex you can use [ltrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.ltrim.php) with a character mask. If your strings never start with a number:

```
$new_str = ltrim($team_1_name, "0123456789[] ");
```

else you could check if the first char is a bracket:

```
$new_str = $team_1_name[0] == '[' ? ltrim($team_1_name, '0123456789[] ') : '';
```